# Fitting 2D gaussian surface in R

Tags: r, matlab, 2d, gaussian, surface

Is it possible to fit a 2D gaussian surface to a data (of form x,y,z) in R, using the equation:

> t=c*exp(-(x-x0)^2/(2*sigmax^2)-(y-y0)^2/(2*sigmay^2))

As it can be done in Matlab http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/284099

And get coefficients from it, as given on Matlab page (for example Coefficients with 95% confidence bounds: a1, sigmax,    sigmay, x0, and y0).

Comment: one approach would be `optim` with minimized function sum of squared differences. You can also use `nls`

Comment: I tried `optim` and it gives result but if I change the start values the results change. I am not able to understand, how should I decide the correct start values?

Comment: I found a link that is really helpful in estimating starting parameters - [How to choose initial values for nonlinear least squares fit] (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62995/how-to-choose-initial-values-for-nonlinear-least-squares-fit)